# Accessing contact information of a facebook app user

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have access_token for facebook application. Is there a way I can get the contact information(phone-number) of the user of my facebook application?

Below is the url which returns me all the public information like name, location, education etc.. but not any contact information

```
https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=XXXX....
```

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't get a phone number from the Graph API. You can get an email though if you have the email extended permission: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions. If you are a whitelisted app I believe you can send Facebook messages as well through the API.